# How to reference the id of elements in a repeat in JavaScript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I was trying to style an `apex:inputFile` to show the name of the file into the box. here what I came to and it works:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Insert file" rendered="{!if(fileUpload == true, true, false)}" style="text-align:right" headerClass="headerTextAlign">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.FileInput_slds_copy}"/>
    <apex:inputFile value="{!wrapper.file.Body}" fileName="{!wrapper.file.Name}" id="file" styleClass="assistive-text" onchange="document.getElementById('fileName').textContent = this.files[0].name"/>
    <apex:outputLabel styleClass="file-selector__body" for="file">
        <span class="file-selector__button button button_neutral" id="fileName + {!wrapper.product.id}">
            Upload File
        </span>
    </apex:outputLabel>
</apex:column>
```

the problem is that there can only be a single element on a page with the same id, and since this is a `apex:colomn` in an `apex:pageBlockTable` with the objects being iterated over a List with `apex:repeat`, there are many span with the same id, resulting in the first button being the only one with an id, and when I upload a file on an other line, the text of the document is always shown on the first line.

[image: image of the table]

So I tried to make the id of each of the `Span` to be a little different, so they can exist.

```
<span class="file-selector__button button button_neutral" id="fileName + {!wrapper.product.id}">
```

it works, my elements on my page each have a specific Id now, but I don't know how to reference that Id in my javaScript code so it knows which is the id. How can I manage to do that. Or is there an other olution than changing the Id for my problem?

In other words, I want to get the Id of the product that is a row on the pageBlockTable when I click on a button on that row

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY can't get access to the id, you can try this:

```
<span class="{!'spanfileName' + wrapper.product.id}"></span>
```

Define your input with a styleClass that will tell the script where to look:

```
<apex:inputFile 
value="{!temp}"
id="file" 
styleClass="{!'fileName' + wrapper.product.id}" assistive-text"
onchange="getFile(this);"/>
```

In the script, find the element and append:

```
<script>
  function getFile(source) {
    console.log('hey');
    let element = document.getElementsByClassName('span' + source.classList[0])[0];
    element.textContent = source.files[0].name;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I dont think I can reference {!wrapper.product.id} in a javascript tho, I just get an error in my DevTools console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: I tried a small function for the onClick event, function test(){console.log('{!$Component.wrapper.product.id}');}.
there is not error message, but nothing is printed in the console

Comment: I've got a plan... give me a few mins

Comment: I think I found my problem, function test(){console.log('{!wrapper.product.id}');} is working. I just read somewhere that $Component was nesessary, but it's not true. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

For the Span:

```
<span class="file-selector__button button button_neutral" id="fileName{!wrapper.product.id}">
```

For the onchange Event: `onchange="document.getElementById('fileName'+'{!wrapper.product.id}').textContent = this.files[0].name"/>`

this way, the Ids are unique and can be referenced in javaScript, because each Id have a part where it is the Id of the record on a row of a a pageBlockTable

**!Important:** all the code must be in the onchange field, it must NOT be onchange that calls a JS function. I don't know why, but `'{!wrapper.product.id}'` always give the same Id if the function in in a script block, while it wors fine when the code is directly written in the onchange.